According to John L. McKenzie he stated in his "Catholic Dictionary of the Bible" the words, "person" and "nature" do not appear in the Bible
"The trinity of persons within the unity of nature is defined in terms of "person" and "nature" which are Greek philosophical terms; actually the terms do not appear in the Bible.
The trinitarian definitions arose as the result of long controversies in which these and others such as "essence" and "substance" were erroneously applied to God by some theologians." (New York, 1965) p. 899.
So my question is, are these terms in the Bible? Person, nature, essence and substance?

I don't think that questions asking for a text are allowed

'Pneuma ho Theos' said Jesus. ('Spirit the Deity' or, colloquially, 'God is a Spirit'.) An entity is located and that nature is described and defined. When one comments on His words, one uses terms to describe what He is conveying in word. One may just repeat His words, but that does not help the hearer who wishes further instruction and clarification. It also helps to define and to combat erroneous ways of thinking. What is your objection to the terms 'person' and 'nature' ? How do you propose, biblically, to convey the concepts ?

The OT does not contain suggestions or foreshadowing of the trinity of persons. What it does contain are the words which the NT employs to express the trinity of persons such as Father, Son, Word, Spirit,  [Dictionary of the Bible, John L. McKenzie, Trinity, p899] McKenzie/Trinity.

For what it is worth, the words in the original Greek phrase are in the New Testament:
The phrase: μία οὐσία, τρεῖς ὑποστάσεις -- one essence/substance in three beings/entities
οὐσία, ας, ἡ -- Luke 15:12-13

οὐσία, ας, ἡ (εἰμί ‘to exist’) that which exists and therefore has substance, property, wealth
--
Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed., p. 740). University of Chicago Press.

ὑπόστασις, εως, ἡ -- 2 Cor. 9:4; 11:17; Heb. 1:3; 3:14; 11:1

ὑπόστασις, εως, ἡ ... ① the essential or basic structure/nature of an entity, substantial nature, essence, actual being, reality ... ② a plan that one devises for action, plan, project, undertaking, endeavor ... ③ The interp. situation, condition ... ④ guarantee of ownership/entitlement, title deed
--
Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed., p. 1041-1041). University of Chicago Press.


Let me include a section from my good ol' dogmatics notes. Then we can draw some conclusions:
5. Holy Trinity

I.  Father, Son, and Holy Ghost.
Three distinct Persons in the one divine Essence and Nature, are one God.

1.  Essence.

    a)  Essence and nature in this connection are concrete nouns.
        1)  They do not signify:
            that which makes a thing what it is, its character or quality.
        2)  They signify:
            a substance, a real entity, a thing in itself.
            cf  Chemnitz: Intelligit ergo Ecclesia nomine essentiae non nomen universale, ut philosophi nominant essentiam humanam, sed naturam divinam revera existentem, quae communicabilis est et communis tribus personis, Patri, Filio et Spiritui sancto et est tota in singulis.127
            cf  Gerhard: Essentia hominum est nomen universale, quod per se revera non existit, sed cogitatione tantum colligitur et intellectu comprehenditur. Essentia vero in divinis non est quiddam imaginarium, ut genus vel species, sed revera existit, quamvis sit communicabilis.128
            cf  Baier: Intelligitur nomine essentiae, sive οὐσία, ipsa natura divina, qualis in se absolute, quaeque una cum attributis simplicissime una ac singularis.129
            cf  Gerhard: Vox οὐσία de Deo usurpata significat numero unam et indivisam essentiam tribus deitatis personis communem, quae non est partialiter in tribus personis, ita ut pars ejus sit in Patre, pars in Filio, pars in Spiritu sancto, sed tota est in Patre, tota in Filio, tota in Spiritu sancto propter infinitatem et immaterialitatem.130

    b)  Scripture uses the word “essence”, οὐσία,
        but only in the sense of property.
        cf  Lk 15:12–13. (= βίος)

    c)   The word “nature”, φύσις, γένεσις.
        1)  Denotes natural character.
            -a) In general.
                cf  Ro 1:26; 2:14,27; 11:21,24; 1 Cor 11:14; Ga 2:15; 4:8; Eph 2:3;—Jas 1:23; 3:6.
            -b) Said of God.
                cf  2 Pe 1:4. (φύσις)
        2)  Used metonymically (abstract for concrete).
            cf  Jas 3:7. (φύσις)

2.  Person.

    a)  A person is: “quod proprie subsistit ”,
        having self-consciousness and self-determination.
        cf  C.A. I, 4(p. 43).
        cf  Chemnitz: Petrus, Paulus, Joannes sunt tres personae, quibus communis est una natura humana, sed differunt valde multum 1. substantia, 2. tempore, 3. voluntate, 4. potentia, 5. operatione.… In Trinitate vero non ita distinguuntur personae, sicut angelus ab angelo, homo ab homine, neque differunt tempore, voluntate, potentia, operatione, sed in personis Trinitatis est coaeternitas, una voluntas, una potentia, una operatio.131

    b)  The Greek word ὑπόστασις (suppositum, fundamentum)
        is not used in the meaning of person in the N.T.
        cf  2 Co 9:4; 11:17; He 3:14; 11:1.
        cf  He 1:3 (: essence, nature; not: person).
        Note. Metonymy: id quod fundamentum habet.
        1)  opposed to φαντασία etc. ἔμφασις
            (e.g. φαντασίαν μὲν ἔχειν πλούτου ὑπόστασίν δὲ μή)
        2)  qualitas, natura (He 1:3),
        3)  animi stabilitas, confidentia.

    c)  The word πρόσωπον (facies, vultus).
        1)  Face.
            cf  Mt 6:16,17; 17:2,6; etc.
        2)  Adverbially: before, on, in the presence of, etc.
            cf  Mal 3:1; Mt 11:10; Lk 2:31; Ac 3:13; 13:24; 25:16;—Lk 21:35—Ac 3:20 (19); act 5:41;—2 Cor 5:12; 10:7;—2 cor 2:10
        3)  Metonymically: person ( pars pro toto).
            cf  2 Cor 1:11; 4:6; Col 2:1; etc.
        4)  Pronominally.
            cf  Lk 9:51,53; Re 20:11; etc.
        5)  Applied to inanimate things.
            cf  Lk 12:56; Ac 17:26; Jas 1:11; etc.
        6)  Person, with reference to social, financial, political, etc. standing.
            cf  Mt 22:16 coll Lk 20:21 λαμβάνειν πρόσωπον.
            Gal 2:6; Jude 16.
        7)  See also προσωπολημπτέω and its derivatives.
            cf  Jas 2:9;—Ac 10:34;—Ro 2:11; Jas 2:1; etc.

Your source is incorrect in that the nouns, person and nature do actually appear in the bible.  However, your source might be on the right track in that, they are not used in the same way as they are used in the Trinitarian discussions leading up to the Nicene (and following) creeds.
One of the facts we have to wrestle with is that we use these words so often today (nature, substance, person, etc.) as if they were always agreed on.  There were actually lengthy discussions across the Mediterranean (and in other territories too) as to what vocabulary should actually be used to label the deep and rich theological concepts we have handed down to us in the bible. So there were various parties that proposed language. And, sadly, they weren't always consistent in their usage (at least to begin with).
For example, one of the severe criticisms that Nestorius faced is that he used "face" ⲡⲣⲟⲥⲱⲡⲟⲛ as word to describe the nature of the Christ.  It was considered to be too vague to carry the theological weight of what the word had to carry. However, what is not considered as much is the fact that Nestorius was not alone in using the term for what we could call "nature." consider Hippolytus:

Ⲇⲩⲟ ⲙⲉⲛ ⲟⲩⲕ ⲉⲣⲱ ⲑⲉⲟⲩⲥ, ⲁⲗⲗ ⲏ ⲉⲛⲁ, ⲡⲣⲟⲥⲱⲡⲁ ⲇⲉ ⲇⲩⲟ, ⲟⲓⲕⲟⲛⲟⲙⲓⲁⲛ ⲇⲉ ⲧⲣⲓⲧⲏⲛ, ⲧⲏⲛ ⲭⲁⲣⲓⲛ ⲧⲟⲩ ⲁⲅⲓⲟⲩ Ⲡⲛⲉⲩⲙⲁⲧⲟⲥ.
Translation: “on the one hand, I do not say that there are two gods, but one, and two “prosopa”, and a third ‘economy’—the grace of the Holy Spirit.

Also Cyril of Alexandria:

Ⲙⲓⲁ ⲅⲁⲣ ⲏ ⲧⲏⲥ ⲑⲉⲟⲧⲏⲧⲟⲥ ⲫⲩⲥⲓⲥ ⲉⲛ ⲡⲣⲟⲥⲱⲡⲱ ⲧⲉ ⲕⲁⲓ ⲩⲡⲟⲥⲧⲁⲥⲉⲓ ⲡⲁⲧⲣⲟⲥ ⲉⲧ ⲕⲁⲓ ⲩⲓⲟⲩ ⲕⲁⲓ ⲏⲁⲅⲓⲟⲩ ⲡⲛⲉⲩⲙⲁⲧⲟⲥ
Translation:  “For one is the nature of the Godhead in both ‘prosopon’ and essence of the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit.”

Likewise, here is a quote from Eusebius:

Ⲡⲱⲥ ⲇⲉ ⲉⲧⲁⲡⲉⲓⲛⲱⲥⲉⲛ ⲉⲁⲩⲧⲟⲛ ⲩⲡⲏⲕⲟⲟⲥ ⲅⲉⲛⲟⲙⲉⲛⲟⲥ ⲧⲱ ⲡⲁⲧⲣⲓ; ⲧⲟ ⲅⲁⲣ ⲩⲡⲁⲕⲟⲩⲉⲓⲛ ⲧⲟⲛⲇⲉ ⲧⲱⲇⲉ ⲇⲩⲉⲓⲛ ⲅⲉⲛⲟⲓⲧ’ ⲁⲛ ⲡⲣⲟⲥⲱⲡⲱⲛ ⲡⲁⲣⲁⲥⲧⲁⲧⲓⲕⲟⲛ.
Translation:  “So how did he humble himself becoming obedient to the Father?  For the obedience that one [Jesus] entered into with [ⲇⲩⲱ] Him [the Father] would have been [that type that] had shown/sustained ‘prosopa.’  (the second half of that was difficult)

(citations are from The Bazaar of Hericleides; Appendix III; The word ⲡⲣⲟⲥⲱⲡⲟⲛ; and appendix IV)
So thus far my points are these:

Many of the words do show up in the bible
They are not used, however, in the same way as they are in the Trinitarian discussions leading into the 4th century and beyond

With that in mind we can address your final issue: were these words "erroneously applied to God by some theologians?"
The difficulty with this question is that it doesn't take into consideration translation.  Each language has a certain toolkit for each word. Some words have more than one meaning. Others have only a few. And it's hard to take words from one context and find a corresponding word that fits the concept in the target language. Sometimes (as in the case of the word, Trinity) a word has to even be made up to describe the concept/teaching in the bible.
So, my question for the author of that section of the "Catholic dictionary of the bible" is that, if the words of the Nicean (and following) ages are not suitable, then what words would have been?  For, I can assure you, whatever words that could have been held up as a replacement would have been just as unwieldy. And most-likely, whatever words the author of that article would have chosen would have been much more open to misunderstanding. And, as a result, the author of that article would have been exiled just as surely as Nestorius was.
So finally then, just as with the word, Trinity, the words aren't in the bible (at least in with the same theological content as in their creedal context), but the concepts/teachings are.  In that sense they are biblical.
